# Force use WAN for internet even if LAN is connected?

Tags: wifi, pi-4

I have two CPEs. One fast 4G CPE (High Speed, 150 GB/m and one slow 3G CPE (2 MBPS,U/L)

**Primary** **4G CPE** which is basically my primary high-speed internet access is shared through a router and switch for LAN connections. Pi's ethernet is connected to this network. I access Plex, Sonarr, Deluge installed on Pi through the wired network backed by high-speed 4G CPE.

I have another **secondary** **3G CPE** (wireless only, no ethernet port) which is slow but has unlimited download.  Pi's WiFi is connected to this other slow 3G CPE.

My use case is I have to download using Secondary Wireless only 3G CPE and use Pi's LAN(backed by 4G CPE) only to access home network and Plex etc.

**Scenario 1** - When I connect both WAN and LAN, Pi connects to internet through LAN only.

**Scenario 2** - When I connect to LAN and WAN but disable internet using LAN from Router, the internet doesn't work. Pi doesn't use WAN internet when LAN is connected even if it doesn't have internet access

**Scenario 3** - I download stuff by running `sudo ifconfig eth0 down` so Pi has only WiFI and it downloads from slow 3G Network

**Scenario I want - Connected to LAN with internet access disabled from Router and only have home network access. Connected to WAN and used to access internet through 3G CPE.**

How Do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple routing problem. You can route local traffic through **eth0** and route all other traffic to the internet through **wlan0** by setting the default route to this interface. For example I use these ip addresses on the RasPi:

```
rpi ~$ ip -4 -brief addr
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8
eth0             UP             192.168.50.246/24
wlan0            UP             192.168.30.117/24
```

The unmodified routing table for this looks:

```
rpi ~$ ip route
default via 192.168.50.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 192.168.50.246 metric 202
default via 192.168.30.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.30.117 metric 303
192.168.30.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.30.117 metric 303
192.168.50.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.50.246 metric 202
```

You have two default routes. This is what you makes your problems. The kernel can only use one, of course. It uses the one with the lowest metric and that is the route through **eth0** with metric 202. All traffic to the internet (destination ip addresses not belonging to local networks -> default route) goes through **eth0** but there is no internet. If you shutdown interface **eth0** then also its default route is deleted and the route with lower metric is used. That's the connection through **wlan0** and there you find the internet.

To fix this just delete the wrong default route:

```
rpi ~$ sudo ip route del default via 192.168.50.1 dev eth0
```

If you use Raspbian default **dhcpcd** networking you can make it persistent by adding this to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
interface eth0
nogateway
```

If using **systemd-networkd** you have to modify the `.network` file in `/etc/systemd/network/` that matches the interface **eth0** (section `[Match]`). There you have to add this if you use DHCP on this interface:

```
[DHCP]
UseRoutes=no
```

If you defined a static ip address there then just omit the `Gateway=` option in section `[Network]`.

Answer (score 0):

I followed @Ingo's suggestion and it worked.

I'm running Openmediavault 5 on Raspbian buster for Pi 4 so I had to modify the below file(s):

```
ls /etc/systemd/network/

> 10-openmediavault-eth0.link     10-openmediavault-vethca8e950.link    
> 10-openmediavault-wlan0.link     99-default.link
> 10-openmediavault-eth0.network  10-openmediavault-vethca8e950.network 
> 10-openmediavault-wlan0.network  openmediavault-eth0.network
```

I added to `[Network] 
          DHCP=yes`

```
[DHCP]
UseRoutes=no
```

To both the files through `sudo nano`

```
10-openmediavault-eth0.network
openmediavault-eth0.network
```

And it works now as internet is accessed through `wlan0` only. Though `sudo ip route` shows `wan0` as default route

```
sudo ip route

default via 192.168.8.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.8.100 metric 1024 
192.168.31.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.31.68
```

Comment: Welcome.  We're glad you're here.  On Stack Exchange, answers are for, um, answers.  You may not be able to comment yet, but you could edit your original question with the information you've put here.

Comment: `interface eth0` with `nogateway` is only for use with `dhcpcd`, not for `systemd-networkd`. I have updated my answer with details for `systemd-networkd`. But if you are happy with your settings, its OK, but I don't understand it.

Comment: This seems like it is intended to be an answer to me, but if not you should update the question with this information rather than posting it as an answer as Bob Brown indicated.